# Is FOR EACH STATEMENT Supported in Trigger?

Tags: postgresql

After reading docs, thought `For Each Statement` covers `For Each Row` and is more efficient, so I created a generic trigger function and applied to all tables contains column `editts` (stands for edit-timestamp without timezone, so we know when this record is updated).

```
CREATE FUNCTION public._tr_updateeditts()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
    new.editts = now();
    return new;
end;
$BODY$;

create trigger _tr_updateeditts_tbl_product before update 
    on public.product  -- table product has column [editts]
    for each statement execute procedure public._tr_updateeditts();
```

But, `product.editts` is never updated. Changed the above to `for each row` works. My Postgresql is v12

Comment: You needed to read more of the docs. [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html) "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error."

Comment: `for each statement` might be more efficient depending on what you want to do. It does not allow editing individual rows (apart from executing a separate `UPDATE` statement) unlike `before each row` triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify the data in statement level triggers, and the variable `NEW` won't be set. To do that, you need a row level trigger.

Statement level triggers may be more efficient since they are not called for each row, but if you need to modify each row, only a row level trigger will do.

Comment: Based on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-trigger.html, seems `statement` not support `before`, is it right?

Comment: No, you can have statement level `BEFORE` triggers.